# how to save pdf reports automatically in database?

Tags: java, mysql, pdf, jakarta-ee, birt

My programming language is java. My application is a web based application. I am using BIRT for generating pdf reports but the requirement is to automatically save them to the database after viewing the pdf report. In BIRT the pdf document is generated on the fly from the rpt templates. When user clicks on a URL the pdf document is displayed by the BIRT viewer application.

The requirement is once the pdf is generated i need to save a copy of the pdf file in the MySql database. This should happen automatically. once the user views the pdf (when the pdf is generated on the fly) the copy of the pdf file should get saved in the database.

Please let me know, how i can achieve this?

Comment: can you post your sample url how you are generating the pdf report?

Answer (score 0):

It depends con how you use your database, direct jdbc, hibernate, ... But basically you have to do following:

- design an entity (*and table*) to hold the blob.
- don't use BLOB in MySQL is very small, better LONGBLOB.
- create a `java.sql.Blob` from file, usually you have to get an inputstream from file.
- attach blob to hibernate entity, query param, ...
- persist.

I would rather prefer to store files in a different entity/table, and also store file name, size, MIME type, date, ... These attributes will be helpful later.

Use a 1:1 por 1:N relationship between the entity owning the file and the file entity.

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi I am using jdbc. what ever you have described, I am doing that process already. If somebody gives pdf as input in the html form then this will work. but my question is how to save them automatically. How to get the inputstream of the pdf that is generated on the fly in BIRT?

Comment: Ah! Ok, sorry. Easy, and not so bad option is to store PDF report as a tmp file, get input stream, do Blob job and delete temp file. This may sound ineficient, but it requires less memory than transforming PDF to bytearray and then getting input stream. If you don't want to worry about temp file deletion, you can use `FileCleaningTracker` from apache commons.

Comment: Can't you write a script that is started in the onRender event of the PDF generation? Or make a custom emitter that also sends the PDF somewhere.

Comment: I think the problem is not where, but how. To create a Blob you need an input stream, to create an input stream you need a source, that is a File, a bytearray, ... Can you convert the on memory PDF object to a bytearray or input stream?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to malaguna's answer, the key is to first store the PDF inside the DB and *then* serve it to the client. This requires basic knowledge of JDBC and web programming. Look at the source code of the servlet sample application (that you seem to be using). You just have to save the PDF output as a BLOB inside your database (as malaguna proposed) before returning it to the client.