# Save pdf report on database using BIRT

Tags: java, hibernate, reporting, birt

So, I'm trying to save the pdf report in database using service methode. I saw that there's a way to specify the output of the generated report by calling : pdfOptions.setOutputStream(output). But how can I call my save methode this way?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064385/how-to-save-pdf-reports-automatically-in-database) but i'm stack at the persist point

I apreciate any advice

```
    PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
    pdfOptions.setOutputFormat(FORMAT_PDF);
    pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
    pdfOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());//opens report on browser
    runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are streaming the output directly to the client with

```
pdfOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());//opens report on browser
```

If you do this, your output gets consumed and you'll not be able to save it to the database.

I would use a "tee" like approach, you know, with one input stream and two output streams.

You could write that yourself, our you just use something like the [Apache TeeOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html).

This could look like this:

```
OutputStream blobOutputStream = ...; // for writing to the DB as BLOB.
OutputStream teeStream = TeeOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), blobOutputStream);
pdfOptions.setOutputStream(teeStream);
```